# Cluster shape and fill color in dot

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to build this graph
[image] that is the result of this:

```
digraph g { 
//Initial settings
rankdir="LR";
margin="0,0";
node[fontsize=16,fixedsize=true,width=0.7,shape=circle];
edge[fontsize=16];
ratio=fill;

//Start point for arrow
start [shape=point,style="invis",width=0];
start -> 0;

subgraph cluster0 {
    style=filled;
    fillcolor=green;
    node [fontsize=16,fixedsize=true,width=0.7,shape=circle, style=filled, color = black, fillcolor=lightgrey];
    //FW Transitions;
    13 -> 12;
    13 -> 9;
    13 -> 7;
    9 -> 11;

    //BW Transitions
    edge [color=green];
    12 -> 13 ;
    11 -> 13;
    11 -> 7;

    //LVL Transitions
    edge[color=red;style=solid];
    7->9;
}

//FW Transitions
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 ;
0 -> 13 [style=dotted];
1 -> 3 -> 5;
0 -> 2;
0 -> 1 ;

//BW Transitions
edge [color=green,constraint=false];
5->7;
edge[constraint=true]
10 -> 12;

//LVL Transitions
edge[color=red;style=solid];

//CONSTRAINT transitions
node [shape=plaintext];
edge[style=invis];
d0 -> d1 -> d2 -> d3 -> d4 -> d5 
2 -> 13 -> 1;
d2 -> 4 -> 12 -> 9 -> 7 -> 3;

//Ranking, order by distance from start
{ rank = same; 0; d0; }
{ rank = same; 1; 2; d1;13;}
{ rank = same; 4; 3; 12; 9; 7; d2;}
{ rank = same; 6; 5; d3;11;}
{ rank = same; 8; d4;}
{ rank = same;  10; d5;}

//Final states
//6[shape=doublecircle]; 
//7 [shape=doublecircle]; 
}
```

Everything seems to work just fine except for the cluster fill color. I want the cluster to be filled with a color to point it out. I tried with both color and fillcolor attributes but nothing happened.

Is this because of the invisible edges I used for the constraints or is it related to the fact I ranked the nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to generate your graph, graphviz actually prints lots of warnings:

> warning: 2 was already in a rankset ...
>   ...

A node cannot be part of multiple subgraphs. The following line

```
{ rank = same; 1; 2; d1;13;}
```

actually defines a subgraph. Some of those nodes are already used in cluster0, hence the warnings.

If you comment all the lines starting with `{ rank=same; ...`, the warning disappears, and the cluster's background color appears. Of course there probably are other problems with the graph now...